# Axios throwing "internal server 500" error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So. I have been trying to fix a bug in my webapp. When a axios POST request is sent then the data gets saved after few moment.
Also I narrowed it down to a cause that the API is throwing a "500 (Internal server error)", but somehow the data still gets updated (after few moment).

My code until here looks like this:

```
    changeStatus() {
        const { match: { params } } = this.props;

        let assigned = this.state.projres && this.state.projres.assign
        let fd = new FormData();
        fd.append("projectId", params.pid);
        fd.append("status", "Completed");
        fd.append("assignedToId", assigned);
        axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: `${url}/project/accepted`,
            data: fd,
        })
        .then((response) => {console.log("here is the resp" + fd)},(error) => {console.log("Error for it is" + error)})
           .then(this.props.actions.getDetails(params.pid)
            ).then(console.log("Here it all ends!"))}
```

In my console, the data Iam getting is in sequence like

```
Here it all ends!
```

```
POST http://localhost:8000/project/accepted 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

```
here is the resp[object FormData]
```

The above console response seems weird as well since it doesnt make .then() useful.

Please help, what could be the possible error in the code?
PS: I checked the other APIs and the post data form many times, they all are correct. Also tried in Postman, its working fine there too.

Comment: `.then(this.props.actions.getDetails(params.pid))` will *immediately call* `this.props.actions.getDetails(params.pid)` instead of assigning it as a callback after the promise resolves. Same with `.then(console.log("Here it all ends!"))` - the value is logged immediately and you assign the result of the `console.log` (which is just `undefined`) as the `.then()` handler. Which does nothing.

Comment: Ok got it. But how to overcome this problem? How can I make ```.then(this.props.actions.getDetails(params.pid))``` wait until the data is loaded? With a if condition may be?

Comment: `.then(() => this.props.actions.getDetails(params.pid)`

Comment: Unfortunately didnt helped! Still throws "500" error :(

Comment: That's a server error. You are unlikely to affect it by changing the client-side code. Especially not possible if you change the *handlers for when the request finishes*. Those will not affect the request by definition.

Comment: Okay I will get under it, Thanks for your time VLAZ :)

Comment: can you share code for the API server side

Comment: Share the server side code and provide the error on the server.